# add row values into single column MYSQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I have this data.

```
 create table student
(
   student_id int,
   name varchar(50)
 )

 create table student_option
(
   student_option_id int, 
   student_id int,
   s_option  varchar(50)
 )  
 insert into student
(
student_id,
name
)values(1,'John'),(2,'Martin')

insert into student_option
(
  student_option_id,
  student_id,
  s_option
  )values(1,1,'A'),(2,1,'B'),(3,2,'C'),(4,2,'D')

select * from student 
select * from student_option
```

I want the output to be displayed as

```
  student_name     options
    John             A, B
    Martin           C, D
```

what is the most optimized way to do this in MYSQL5.6

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one should work. You basically use [GROUP_CONCAT function from MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html) and GROUP BY name after.

```
select s.name, group_concat(o.s_option) 
  from student s 
  left join student_option o on (s.student_id = o.student_id) 
  group by s.name;
```

Result:

```
name    s_option

John    B,A    
Martin  D,C
```